# How to open MemoryStream in update/modify mode

Tags: c#

I've following code for updating a zip file (in memory and later write to disk once done), however I get an error message as below

> System.ArgumentException: 'Update mode requires a stream with read,
> write, and seek capabilities

Code:

```
public void Method()
{

  DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\dir");
  var pdfFileSet = directoryInfo.GetFiles().ToList();

  MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  memoryStream.Close();

  SingleZipFileMS(memoryStream, pdfFileSet);
}

public static MemoryStream SingleZipFileMS(MemoryStream memoryStream, List<FileInfo> filesToZip)
{
   int x = ++i;
   Console.WriteLine("Process: {0}", x);
   using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
   {
      foreach (var file in filesToZip)
         zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(file.FullName, file.Name);
   }
   Console.WriteLine("Process: {0} completed", x);
   return memoryStream;
}
```

Comment: `pdfFileSet` and `i` are not defined in your code. Can you show how to declare these.

Comment: Why do you Close the stream before using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the line `memoryStream.Close();` after `SingleZipFileMS(memoryStream, pdfFileSet);` and it will work. The `ArgumentException: Update mode requires a stream with read, write, and seek capabilities.` is thrown because the MemoryStream is closed when you are using it. So don't close it until afterwards, and you should be fine.

```
public void Method()
{
    var pdfFileSet = new List<FileInfo>() {new System.IO.FileInfo("temp.txt")};
    //Some code
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    //memoryStream.Close();  Move this to after
    SingleZipFileMS(memoryStream, pdfFileSet);
    
    memoryStream.Close(); // Like this
}

public static MemoryStream SingleZipFileMS(MemoryStream memoryStream, List<FileInfo> filesToZip)
{

    using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
    {
        foreach (var file in filesToZip)
            zipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile(file.FullName, file.Name);
    }

    return memoryStream;
}
```

Even neater, would be to use a `using` statement to close the MemoryStream at the proper time.

```
public void Method()
{
    var pdfFileSet = new List<FileInfo>() {new System.IO.FileInfo("temp.txt")};
    //Some code
    using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    SingleZipFileMS(memoryStream, pdfFileSet);
}
```

Comment: ... or probably do something with it. Just closing the stream discards the contents, making the whole zip operation quite pointless.

Comment: @Philip Ngan, That's very nice of you, it works. I tried to give it a twist and it failed again with the same error. I modified the code as `foreach (var batch in pdfFileSet) {SingleZipFileMS(memoryStream, batch)}` Considering pdfFileSet as `List<List<FileInfo>>`

Comment: @Aniruddha, `new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update)` by default will close the stream when it has used it. You can make it keep the stream open by adding a leave stream open flag as the final parameter: `new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Update, true)`

Comment: @PhillipNgan Great! and thank you, once again.